# Following a redirect with phantomjs and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, phantomjs

Hello I want to follow a redirection if that is happening with phantomjs and python3 but I can't get it work and google didn't help me too

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


with open("test", "r") as t:
br = webdriver.PhantomJS()
for line in t.readlines():
    br.get('http://{}'.format(line))
    br.save_screenshot('./screens/{}.png'.format(line))

br.quit()
```

info: "test" is the file where to load the urls from

and I can't take a screenshot of a subdirectory ex: google.com/help but I want that too

Comment: What is the website you are trying to request?

Comment: that doesn't matter just everything that is a redirection